# Shared servlet for fileIO?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-io

Imagine having a `webservice` or `servlet`, which can perform some `fileIO`.
How can I make sure that if more than one client executes the according WS method, that the fileIO is still handled only by one single "thread"? So that no data is lost because several clients trigger the fileIO?

Which direction should I search for?

Comment: This is handled by the Application Server. If you have any problem with the file I/O operation, its because you're using shared resources in your servlet or your WS method that must support synchronization or not use any shared resource at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concrete problem. Are you talking about multiple threads writing to a single same file? If so, how so "data is lost"? How exactly did that happen for you? Which problems exactly are you currently facing? What OS are you using? A bit decent OS platform would namely already lock the file if it's been opened for writing...

Comment: Well, if 2 clients access my webservice method `doFileIO` at the same time, and the fileIO now tries to access the same file. Let's imagine every file process lasts long enough that it is not finished at the time the 2nd client executes this method. How can I now make sure that the Application Server does not try to operate on a file that maybe is already "in process" due to the 1st client?

Comment: Well, if a file is opened for writing by one thread, then it can't be opened for writing by another thread. The thread has to wait until the file is closed. This is all handled transparently by the OS. So as long as you don't share a single `FileOutputStream` reference (which is essentially a single file write lock) between threads, then it should sound logical that you're perfectly safe. A "normal" Java developer already wouldn't share a single `FileOutputStream` instance between threads in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet is likely to just make the underlying method(s) that read/write synchronize on a common object. (eg. the File object could be easiest).

```
private static File theFile = new File("theonetoopen.txt");
...

private void someImportantIOMethod(Object stuff){
    synchronized(theFile){

    //Your file output writing code here.

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use static objects in a Java Web Application, they are unloaded (and freed from memory) when the server application is shutted down.

Comment: ya...they are temporary, but can allow for easy single-threaded access/coordination.  I don't really understand your concern...especially because in this case the "File" object is just a string/it isn't attached to any open readers, writers, etc.