# Synchronize file object

Tags: java, synchronized

From what I know and researched, the `synchronized` keyword in Java lets synchronize a method or code block statement to handle multi-threaded access. If I want to lock a file for writing purposes on a multi-threaded environment, I <strike>must</strike> should use the classes in the [Java NIO package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) to get the best results. Yesterday, I come up with a question about handling a shared servlet for file I/O operations, and BalusC comments are good to help with the solution, but the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957978/1065197) confuses me. I'm not asking community "burn that post" or "let's downvote him" (note: I haven't downvoted it or anything, and I have nothing against the answer), I'm asking for an explanation if the code fragment can be considered a good practice

```
private static File theFile = new File("theonetoopen.txt");

private void someImportantIOMethod(Object stuff){
    /*
        This is the line that confuses me. You can use any object as a lock, but
        is good to use a File object for this purpose?
    */
    synchronized(theFile) {
        //Your file output writing code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because now you're over 4000.

Comment: @Hassan whoever it is and whatever reputation it is, don't do that until u feel that question/answer is helpful.

Comment: @Nandkumar I do like this question, I just thought it was amusing.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:What do you mean in your comment in the OP you link to `Don't use static objects in a Java Web Application...`. I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @user384706 static objects in Java Web Applications could lead to memory leaks because they are created every time you deploy the application (where the classes are loaded) but they're not freed when you undeploy the application, the static objects remains in the JVM until you stop it, this means shutting down the Web Application Server (Tomcat, JBoss or whatever you use).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:Are you sure about this?Doesn't each web app have each own classloader?

Comment: @user384706 yes, every web app has its own classloader, this is why the static objects are recreated on every deploy, but when you undeploy the application, the old static objects remain in memory (they are not GCed). The only way to free them is to stop the JVM. For more info, see [Scope of Java static member in web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6389337/1065197), and if you have more questions about this please make another thread :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have followed your link only to find out it claims the exact opposite of what you claim here: every classloader makes its own instance of the statically-referenced object and, by inference, that reference is destroyed upon class unloading.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the question is: when is the class unloaded? this happens when you undeploy the web app?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza All the answer under your link states is that there are multiple classloaders, exactly what user384706 stated himself. There are **issues** with unloading classes on undeployment, yes, but they do not fail to unload by design, as your comment suggests.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that really depends on the JVM implementation. This happened in a project, when we use the profiler we found that there were living objects in the JVM (the class was not unloaded and its static object was alive), this is why I personally don't recommend to use static variables in Web Application.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, this is valid advice and static singletons are known problems in this area. However, they are just the symptoms: even without them, if your classes fail to unload, you are in for an `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree with your last comment.

Comment: You are arguing about class loader leaks? That comes mainly when you are using ThreadLoacal right? As for static object usage its not directly related to the leaks unless its being used in a specific way. I dont think that "Don't use static objects in web applications" is very good advice. Also http://frankkieviet.blogspot.com/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html

Comment: @Thihara The question has been answered. We could spend more time and comments talking about this matter. It would be better to start a new post/thread about classloaders on web apps. By the way, the link is great and gives a good explanation about classloaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not about locking on a File object - you can lock on any object and it does not really matter (to some extent).

What strikes me is that you are using a non final monitor, so if another part of your code reallocates theFile: `theFile = new File();`, the next thread that comes around will lock with a different object and you don't have any guarantee that your code won't be executed by 2 threads simultaneously any more.

Had `theFile` been final, the code would be ok, although it is preferable to use private monitors, just to make sure there is not another piece of code that uses it for other locking purposes.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter that the lock in this case is a File (apart from the missing `final` as noted by ya'll). If anything it is confusing code as it suggests some connection between JRE land and file system land when there (probably) isn't one.

Comment: Yes, the `final` keyword will make the difference, as stated in the post [How Synchronization works in Java?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html). The thing that confused me was locking the code block using a `File` object, indeed I got confused for the Java lock and the OS lock on the file, but I guess these locks are very different.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to lock the file within a single application then it's OK (assuming `final` is added).

Note that the solution won't work if you load the class more than once using different class loaders. For example, if you have a web application that is deployed twice in the same web server, each instance of the application will have its own lock object.

As you mention, if you want the locking to be robust and have the file locked from other programs too, you should use [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) (see the docs, on some systems it is not guaranteed that all programs must respect the lock).

Answer (score 1):

Had you seen: `final Object lock = new Object()` would you be asking?
As @assylias pointed out the problem is that the lock is not `final` here

Answer (score 1):

Every object in Java can act as a lock for synchronization. They are called intrinsic locks. Only one thread at a time can execute a block of code guarded by a given lock.

More on that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Using synchronized keyword for the whole method could have performance impact on your application. That's why you can sometimes use synchronized block.

You should remember that lock reference can't be changed. The best solution is to use final keyword.